# Dynamically enable alert on webbutton

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

We have a tabbed page called Contact. It is one of many tabbed pages linked to a "parent" page: Student.aspx.

Within the Contact page, there are fields for overall household address information, and then grids that show individual contacts for the student.

If the user changes data in the household address information and then tries to ADD a new contact (a webbutton in the form), a popup box pops up and asks if the user wants to save the address information. If the user makes the same change, but then clicks on the Detail button contained within the grid, the contact detail screen opens, and the user loses the changes made to the household info.

I want an alert to popup if `HasUserChanges = true` and the Details button has been clicked.

Currently, I'm checking for changes in the "parent" contact page and then trying to dynamically set properties in a control that is contained in a grid.

I removed the OnCommand property from the webbutton (WebButtonContactDetails)

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <sis:WebButton ID="WebButtonContactDetail" runat="server" UseCssHover="true" UsePostBack="true"
        AutoTipKey="Detail" IsSmallButton="true" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/LBL/wbtnDetail_small.gif"
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Order").ToString() + Eval("ContactType").ToString() + Eval("Relation.Value").ToString() %>'
        CausesValidation="false" OnClick="WebButtonContactDetail_Click"
        UseAsync="false"   />
</ItemTemplate>
```

and added an onClick property, `WebButtonContactDetails_Click`.

```
protected void WebButtonContactDetail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var closelink = (Control) sender;
    GridDataItem row = (GridDataItem)closelink.NamingContainer;
    string firstCellText = row.Cells[0].Text;
    WebButton test = (WebButton)row.FindControl("WebButtonContactDetail");
    if (HasUserChanges)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "Submit", "setTimeout('ShowAlert(\\'" + "You need to save your changes!" + "\\',\\'\\', 0, \\'\\', \\'Student Contacts\\', false)', 500);", true);
    }
    else
    {
        test.Command += new CommandEventHandler(StudentContacts_LinkButtonDetails_Command_H);
    }       
}
```

The alert box isn't awesome to look at, but it works.

Anyone have a better/more elegant way to do this?

Comment: You should add the relevant code to the issue,  try to make a [mcve]

Comment: If I was able to get anything to come close to working I would have, and I probably wouldn't have needed to post anything.  But thanks for the help.

Comment: Alright, thanks to actually helpful people, I think I was able to kluge this enough to make users happy:

Comment: I've moved your code into your question and tried to clear it up a bit; [so] is a Q+A site rather than a forum so answers are reserved for answers whilst you can use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38251463/edit) button to add new information. I'm not sure of a solution but hopefully your question is clearer for others that might